# Stop for loop upon returning value

Tags: c, arrays, loops

This is the relevant function:

```
int computerChoice() {
int x, y;
for (y=0;y<=2;y++) {
    for (x=0;x<=2;x++) {        
        if (matrix[y][x] == 'a') {
            return(1);
        } else {
            matrix[y][x] = 'b';
            return(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And this is the relevant `main()` code:

```
char matrix[3][3];
int duplicate1 = 0;
do {
    duplicate1 = computerChoice();
} while(duplicate1 == 1);
```

I'm attempting to scan through a `3x3` two dimensional array and check sequentially if each one is equal to `"a"`. If so I want the function to return a `"1"` and continue checking. Once it finds an entry that is not equal to `"a"` it should set that entry equal to b, return 0 and stop looping.

I get some really weird results. If `[1][1]` has an `"a"` in it, the function doesn't do anything but just "freezes". If `[2][2]` has an `"a"` in it, the function correctly places a `"b"` in the entry `[1][1]`.

This also happens if other entries are already filled.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your loops execute precisely once, since you always return immediately in the first round.

Comment: What does "I want to return 1 and continue checking" mean? Either you return, or you don't return.  You cannot return and also not return.

Comment: @KerrekSB Unless you're [Schrödinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat).

Comment: This is a poor design choice, why do you need to return a 1? Just set whatever is not equal to a `b` and then return the array at the end, much simpler.

Comment: See the accepted answer for what I was trying to accomplish,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your implementation seems buggy the code should continue till it is finding 'a' in each cell.If it doesn't find 'a' it should set it to 'b' and return 0. the loop will stop automatically when you return.
If both the loop completes that means every cell in matrix contains 'a'. and you should return 1;

```
int computerChoice() {
int x, y;
    for (y=0;y<=2;y++) {
        for (x=0;x<=2;x++) {        
            if (matrix[y][x] == 'a') {
                continue;
            } 
        else {
               matrix[y][x] = 'b';
               return(0);
            }
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: That's it! I totally forgot about using continue. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming what you mean is "I want to process the entire array, and return 1 if I ever found an `a`, and 0 otherwise". That can be achieved like so:

```
int found = 0;

for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j != 3; ++j)
    {
        if (matrix[i][j] == 'a') { found = 1; }
        else                     { matrix[i][j] = 'b'; }
    }
}

return found;
```

(By changing to `++found`, you can also return the *number* of occurrences of `'a'`.)

---

If on the other hand you want to return 0 as soon as you know there's a non-`'a'` in your data, it's simpler:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
    for (size_t j = 0; j != 3; ++j)
        if (matrix[i][j] != 'a') { matrix[i][j] = 'b'; return 0; }

return 1;
```

Comment: That's what I wanted. But @Abhipranay Chauhan beat you to it. You get my vote though :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you mean by "return 1 and continue checking". I will assume that you want to scan the whole array, and return 1 if every position is an `a`; otherwise, return 0 and set the first position that was not an `a` to `b`. Here's the code:

```
int computerChoice() {
    int x, y;
    for (y=0;y<=2;y++) {
        for (x=0;x<=2;x++) {        
            if (matrix[y][x] != 'a') {
                matrix[y][x] = 'b';
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```